# Segmentation Fault in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

My code is giving me a segmentation fault and I can't seem to find what I'm doing wrong:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
char find(char name[], char allNames[][10], int length)
{
int i=0;
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
if (strcmp(allNames[i],name) == 1) {
printf("%i",i);
return *name;
}
}
return -1;
}

main(){
  char allNames[][10] = {"cat","dog","frog","log","bog"};
  char name[] = "log";
int length=5;
  printf("%s",find(name,allNames,length));

}
```

I'm really keen to understand all the mechanisms happening here and what I'm doing wrong for tomorrows exam. Thanks for your help!

**EDIT:** Really Appreciate the answers and information guys! I'm really quite new to C and just getting used to what every thing means. The particular exam question I am looking at is :

*(a) The following function is intended to find the string name in the array
allNames. If found, it returns the position of name in the array. If not
found, it returns -1. Modify the code so that it works correctly.*

```
int find(char name[], char allNames[][10])
{
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
if (allNames[i] == name) {
return name;
}
}
return -1;
}
```

And I'm trying to get a program to work within these parameters. Cheers :)

Comment: Doing wrong (1): not using a debugger.

Comment: your fuction retunrs char. not char *.

Comment: indent your code, check gcc warnings.

Comment: @Dave, If you want to return the position , then change `return name` to `return i`. And then, you also need to rewrite your `printf` . If you want print the string, use  `allNames[your_return_position]`  when your_return_position>=0. Or just to print the position `printf("find at position: %d",find(name,allNames,length))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct reason for your `Segmentation Fault` here is because the code tried to print the `char` type with `%s`(which needs an address value).

> ```
> void main()
> {
>  char c = 'a';
>  printf("%s", c); // will cause Segmentation fault here
> }
> ```

Back to your code, that is

```
char find(char name[], char allNames[][10], int length)//return char 
printf("%s",find(name,allNames,length));
```

The minimal change to make it work as follows,

1) To return char*

```
char* find(char name[], char allNames[][10], int length)//return char*
{
  int i=0;
  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (strcmp(allNames[i],name) == 0) { // here should 0
       printf("%i",i);
       return name; // change name* to name
    }
 }
  return NULL; // change to NULL
}
//to print
printf("%s",find(name,allNames,length));
```

2) to return position value

```
    int find(char name[], char allNames[][10])
    {
       for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
          if (allNames[i] == name) {
          return i; // here, change to return i
       }
    }
    return -1;
    }

   //then, you can print like this
    printf("find at position: %d",find(name,allNames,length));
   //or to print string by 
    int pos = find(name,allNames,length);
    if(pos >= 0)
       printf("find the string: %s",allNames[pos]);
```

Answer (score 3):

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d400c9a56d732446

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
char* find(char name[], char allNames[][10], int length)
{
    int i=0;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (!strcmp(allNames[i],name)) {
            printf("%i",i);
            return name;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(){
  char allNames[][10] = {"cat","dog","frog","log","bog"};
  char name[] = "log";
  int length=5;
  printf("%s",find(name,allNames,length));

}
```

Returning a single `char` will do you no good if you're trying to return a string. I would also suggest that you return a `NULL` if you cannot find the string.

Also, include the `int` before main; this is better style.

Comment: Apparently, in the code in the question, he is returning `*name`, which is indeed a `char`, shouldn't be a runtime error because of that?? :\

Comment: @user007 He shouldn't be returning a character anyways; he's specifying printing a string, so why would he return the character? His function itself returns the wrong type. It also might be beacuse it cannot find the terminating '\0' character when it tries to `printf()`.

Comment: `strcmp(allNames[i],name)` --> `!strcmp(allNames[i],name)` or `strcmp(allNames[i],name)==0`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY No, that'll do nothing. He's trying to match a string and return the right one if it's found from the list. Why would he return if it's *not* in the list? That's counter to his intent.

Answer (score 2):

This code is wrong on several levels.

gcc -Wall -Wextra reveals:

```
meh.c:15:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wreturn-type]
 main(){
 ^
meh.c: In function ‘main’:
meh.c:19:3: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
   printf("%s",find(name,allNames,length));
   ^
meh.c:21:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
```

What's up with that? Do you compile with warnings enabled?

I am ignoring the lack of indentation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
char find(char name[], char allNames[][10], int length)
```

What? How about: char *name, **list, int size)

```
{
int i=0;
```

Why set it to 0 here?

```
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
if (strcmp(allNames[i],name) == 1) {
printf("%i",i);
return *name;
```

Have you read strcmp's manpage? It returns **ZERO** when a string matches, so this code makes no sense.

*name is of type char, but you don't want to return a char. You want to return a pointer, no?

```
}
}
return -1;
```

Well, given that you feed that into %s in printf, what do you expect to hapen here? Normally one would return NULL.

```
}

main(){
```

This is obsolete syntax, I don't know where you stole it from. Use 'int main(void)'.

```
  char allNames[][10] = {"cat","dog","frog","log","bog"};
```

Normally people just return such arrays with a NULL pointer, so that these can be iterated over and there is no need to pass anything about the size.

```
  char name[] = "log";
```

Why not char *name = "log".

```
int length=5;
```

Incorrect. It hardcodes the amount of stored strings in allNames table.
      printf("%s",find(name,allNames,length));

```
}
```